# How do i check internet connectivity in remote android device?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

This question might be a duplicate question, but i cant find proper solution.
I have chat app in which i set function for when remote android device on background mode it will get notification by FCM when new message will come(new node added in chatroom).
So

1. if remote device is in the foreground mode than it will get notification by app and its has definitely internet connectivity for this i can set message delivery successfully.
2. if remote device is in the background mode than it will get notification by FCM and its has definitely internet connectivity. for this i can also set message delivery successfully.

So how do i check that remote device is totally offline(no internet connection) or how to check FCM is not success to send notification ?

for example:

```
    if(messegeReceiver(remote device) has no internet connectivity )
    {
       //here i want to change data in firebase//
    }
    else
    {
     //here i want to change data in firebase//
    }
```

I have "Users" node in which every users set device_token while login the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can device checking offline/online mode via set one param in your chat table. When user exit or minimize application then set states to 0 and maximum set to 1.Best way if possible you use firebase real-time database for online offline.

Comment: ok i set 0 when user exit or minimize to app but at that time  FCM will trigger and send notification on remote device and remote device delivered message.

Comment: But i want to check device has internet connection  or not. if not than delivery is pending, and if yes than FCM automatically send notification.

Comment: Add one api for manage only online offline status with 0 and 1.From api side send notification to both side.

Comment: Use <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" /> and set broadcast receiver and call api to set connectivity change status. But not possible to check device have no internet but have internet is possible.So you just call api when device have internet so server send undelivered message to other device.

Comment: Will class A extends BroadcastReceiver{...}  also work when app in background ?

Comment: Yes..
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
        receiver = new NetworkChangeReceiver();
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

Comment: is this code write in any particular activity. i dont know about it, please suggest example

Comment: If you used fragment then put it to in your main activity only

Comment: please write your answer how to write in mainActivity if i am not using fragment

Answer (score 0):

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
NetworkChangeReceiver receiver = new NetworkChangeReceiver();
regisenter code hereterReceiver(receiver, filter); 

public static class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        public static boolean isOnline(Context context) {

            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            //should check null because in air plan mode it will be null
            return (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected());
        }

        public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {


            ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager)
                    context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            if (connectivity != null) {
                NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
                if (info != null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
                        if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                            if (!isConnected) {

                                relativelayout_connection.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                isConnected = true;


                                return true;

                            }

                        } else {
                            relativelayout_connection.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    }
                }

            } else {
                relativelayout_connection.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                isConnected = false;
                return false;
            }
            return isConnected;

        }

        @Override
        public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {


            // isNetworkAvailable(context);
            if (isOnline(context)) {


            } else {
                relativelayout_connection.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Answer (score 0):

**FCM does not guarantee that the push notification gets delivered. It completely depends upon various factors like internet connection (as you mentioned), OEM behavior, Doze mode etc.**

In your case, you are trying to send messages via FCM from one device to another and shown messages in the form notifications just like any other chat application.

The only problem here is that the FCM does not provide you with delivery parameters in response (image attached) that you are looking for. It only gives count for number of notifications that has been accepted by the gateway i.e. FCM (**success**) and the count for number of notifications that has been rejected by the gateway (**failure**). It also gives the reason for rejection (**error**) message like **NotRegistered**, **MissingRegistrationToken**, etc and you can refer [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) for the same.

My suggestion here would be to have a handshake message in place that acknowledges the delivery of the push notification from the other device. As soon as you receive the push notification send a handshake message via FCM and that gets received by the first device which understands that the push notification has been delivered. In case if the device does not receive the handshake you assume that the message is yet to be delivered.

[image]